# Python GTK+ widget name

Tags: python, gtk

How do I get a widget's "name"?

When I define a GUI using Glade, I can "name" the widgets of the window but how do I recover that property when I have a widget object instance?

I've tried `get_property()`, `get_name()` and `$widget.name` to no avail.

**Update:** I am using GtkBuilder file format (i.e. XML format).

**Resolution:** a fix I have used: use the `set_property("name", name)` method on the widget just after getting it from `GtkBuilder`.

Comment: What format are you using? Glade or GTKBuilder?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I use the class-method form, which works for me:

```
gtk.Buildable.get_name(widget)
```

---

### References

PyGtk: [gtk.Buildable.get_name](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtkbuildable.html#method-gtkbuildable--get-name)

Gtk3: [Gtk.Buildable.get_name](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkBuildable.html#gtk-buildable-get-name)

Quote from [gtk2 GtkBuilder](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtkbuilder.html):

> Prior to GTK+ 2.20, gtk.Builder was setting the "name" property of
>   constructed widgets to the "id" attribute. In GTK+ 2.20 or newer, you
>   have to use gtk.Buildable.get_name() instead of gtk.Widget.get_name()
>   to obtain the "id", or set the "name" property in your UI definition.

---

### Further

There were some reported bugs where GtkBuilder sets the widget name to be the builder ID, or doesn't set it at all. See [Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pygtk/+bug/507739) and [GNOME](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=591085) bugs. I have no idea why the bugs says that it sets the ID instead of the name as I've only ever seen the name not set.

Comment: that's exactly what has been happening on my end!  Thanks for the heads-up!

Answer (score 2):

```
self.builder.get_name(widget)
```

Where widget is the widget object.  Works using Ubuntu's packaged quickly development environment

Comment: Afraid this answer is incomplete and misleading, what is `self.builder` variable? `gtk.Builder` ([gtk2](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkBuilder.html) nor [gtk3](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkBuilder.html)) doesn't have a `get_name` method.

Answer (score 0):

Given the widget `w`, what does `w.get_name()` return?  If `None`, that means the widget has no `name` property.  Maybe you want `gtk.glade.get_widget_name(w)` instead?  (I'm not sure if the `name` property of the widget and the name for it in the Glade XML from which it was created are the same thing...).

Comment: They return "None", as well as `gtk.glade.get_widget_name(w)`.

Comment: @jdupont, and yet you're certain `w` was built from a named entry in a Glade XML file?  Then I'm out of ideas...:-(