# pygtk get widget by name from parent node

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I have a gtk widget and I want to find out if within its descendants there is another widget.  If there is one, I want to return it otherwise return None.  This is a simple recursive problem but I cannot seem to get the right method to do it.

In the glade xml file, I have:

```
  <object class="GtkDialog" id="monkey">
  [...]
       <object class="GtkTreeView" id="ook">
```

and a call to `find(my_monkey_object, 'ook')` should return the GtkTreeView object.
`find()` should be something akin to

```
def find (node, id):
    if node.XXX() == id: return node
    for child in node.get_children():
        ret = find(child, id)
        if ret: return ret
    return None
```

I am not sure which XXX() method I need to use.  `get_name()` looked hopeful but returns the class name of the object and not its "id".  The version I use is pygtk-2.24.

See this [Python GTK+ widget name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489520/python-gtk-widget-name) question for the same problem.

Note that this [bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=591085) kind of explains the issue:  I want the builder ID as from a GTK widget tree.  Sadly, this seems impossible to get...

Comment: I'm not sure how it works in python, but according to the gtk documentation, you can get the "id" name from gtk_buildable_get_name.

Comment: Does `gtk.Buildable(widget).get_name()` not work per comment 19 of that bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the gtk C-api documentation, you can get the glade "id" name like this:

```
name = gtk_buildable_get_name (GTK_BUILDABLE (widget))
```

For pygtk, this is the same as

```
name = gtk.Buildable.get_name(widget)
```

Comment: @ergosys @Sardathrion so the `name` is a pointer?and the `widget` is the widget name?

Answer (score 2):

I guess your node object is a gtk.Container derived class. Maybe `isinstance(node, gtk.TreeView)` is what you are looking for. There is afaik no "id" per se in the `gtk.Widget`-subclasses. The id field belongs to the glade-xml parser.

May i propose something like:

```
def find_child_classes(container, cls):
    return [widget for widget in container.get_children() if isinstance(widget, cls)]
```

Or you keep the builder-object and access the instance by: `builder.get_object('your-object-id')` .

Comment: Your assumption is indeed correct: node is a gtk.Container derived class.  The `isinstance()` method is not ideal as it will match all gtl.TreeView and not just the one named "ook".

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20461465/2015768) has it.

Adapted to use pygi, it looks like:

```
# Copypasta from https://stackoverflow.com/a/20461465/2015768
# http://cdn.php-gtk.eu/cdn/farfuture/riUt0TzlozMVQuwGBNNJsaPujRQ4uIYXc8SWdgbgiYY/mtime:1368022411/sites/php-gtk.eu/files/gtk-php-get-child-widget-by-name.php__0.txt
# note get_name() vs gtk.Buildable.get_name(): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489520/python-gtk-widget-name
def get_descendant(widget, child_name, level, doPrint=False):
  if widget is not None:
    if doPrint: print("-"*level + ": " + (Gtk.Buildable.get_name(widget) or "(None)") + " :: " + (widget.get_name() or "(None)"))
  else:
    if doPrint:  print("-"*level + ": " + "None")
    return None
  #/*** If it is what we are looking for ***/
  if(Gtk.Buildable.get_name(widget) == child_name): # not widget.get_name() !
    return widget;
  #/*** If this widget has one child only search its child ***/
  if (hasattr(widget, 'get_child') and callable(getattr(widget, 'get_child')) and child_name != ""):
    child = widget.get_child()
    if child is not None:
      return get_descendant(child, child_name,level+1,doPrint)
  # /*** Ity might have many children, so search them ***/
  elif (hasattr(widget, 'get_children') and callable(getattr(widget, 'get_children')) and child_name !=""):
    children = widget.get_children()
    # /*** For each child ***/
    found = None
    for child in children:
      if child is not None:
        found = get_descendant(child, child_name,level+1,doPrint) # //search the child
        if found: return found
```